# Paste comma separated content into different cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have the string "1,2,3,4". Is it possible to paste that string into Google Spreadsheets in such a way that each of the comma-separated values goes into a different cell to the right of the selected one?
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwINs.png) is what the spreadsheet would look like after pasting.

Answer (score 9):

Since the file is a CSV. Ensure it is saved with the .CSV extension and upload the file to google sheets.

You also have the option of opening it with Microsoft excel and then pasting the cell formatted text into the google sheet.

Also You can paste the comma separated values into the google sheet and then click the paste icon that appears below the cell and select the 'Split text into columns' Option

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Enter into the spreadsheet

`=SPLIT("1,2,3,4", ",")`

Comment: Great snippet. Just need to replace comma by semicolon: =SPLIT("1,2,3,4"; ",")

Answer (score 0):

First select the cell on of your action and click Data

[1st step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U4ZM.png)

Now, select 'split text to column', it will name it a number

[2nd step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQnvf.png)

now, again goto data and select split text to column open it will transfer every comma separated element into individual columns

[3rd step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6pr2.png)

Answer (score -1):

No. If you try inserting any formula by overwriting the selected cell the data the formula needs will be overwritten, hence not be available to the formula.

You could use say:

```
=split(A1,",")
```

to obtain the results you want to the right of the cell with data in, but this would have to be placed to the right of the cell with data, not in it.

@Treyten's A would also achieve the result you seek except that it would not be to the right of the chosen cell (etc) but in the chosen cell (and to its right etc, assuming the usual LTR).

Similarly with @tks.tman's A. The contents spill out to the right but they do not start in a "cell to the right of the selected one" but *in* the selected one.